# Transform error returned by useFetch in Nuxt3

Tags: fetch, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Is it possible to transform the error returned by `useFetch` in Nuxt3 to a completely custom class instance with custom methods etc.?

I would like to be able to use the `onResponseError` interceptor to create a class instance of my custom error model and re-throw that in the interceptor.

The instance should then be in the returned error object.

```js
const { data, error } = useFetch(url, {
    onResponseError: transformError
})

transformError({ request, response, options }) {
    throw new ApiResponseError(response)
}
```

However, when I try that, I am getting errors in the console like: `TypeError: $setup.error.getErrorMessage is not a function` when I try to access the methods of the `ApiResponseError`.

I guess that the error is not properly serialized & re-instantiated on the client? However, when I tried creating a [payload plugin](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-nuxt-app#payload) for it, I found out that the payload reducer isn't called for the error. *(or at least I think...)*

Here is an example on stack blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-kkmozm?file=app.vue

Answer (score 1):

I created a [replication](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-c9h4j8?file=app.vue) using `nuxt@3.5.3` with this code:

```js
const { data, error } = await useFetch('/api/foo', {
  onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
    if (process.server) console.log({ request, response, options });
    else if (process.client)
      alert(JSON.stringify({ request, response, options }));
  },
});
```

`onResponseError` works as expected and [documented](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch) with this Nuxt version.

What is still not clear to me is why when I first load the replication, `onResponseError` is triggered on the server (`console.log`) while if I edit the project it is triggered on the client (`alert`) but this is maybe due to how stackblitz works.

You are missing `await` from the documentation [example](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch#example), but I tested it also removing it and `onResponseError` is still triggered.

My conclusion is that you may have an error somewhere else in your code, for example by using it outside of setup function, plugin, or route middleware.

**Edit**: Following your feedback in the comments, you can throw a custom error by:

```js
<script setup>
class ApiResponseError extends Error {
  constructor(response) {
    super(response);
    this.message = `Modified ${response._data.message}`;
    // if (process.server) console.log(this.message);
    // else alert(this.message);
  }
}

const { data, error } = await useFetch('/api/foo', {
  onResponseError({ request, response, options }) {
    throw new ApiResponseError(response);
  },
});
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <pre>{{ error.message }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>
```

Now the error message is the modified one.

Otherwise, [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-kwh5us?file=app.vue) is another project using the `error` property instead of `onResponseError` to use a custom `error.vue` page.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution!
I think you misunderstood my question. In your example, a Nuxt error is still in the `error` object returned by `useFetch`. I added an example solution to the question, however, I'm not sure it's the best one.. could it be improved somehow?

Comment: @Matej I edited the response. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you, but I'm still struggling with it a little bit, could you have a look at this? https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-kkmozm?file=app.vue

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. What I noticed is that code for `error` and code for `onResponseError` is processed slightly different.
Also in this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-kwh5us?file=app.vue I had to use `createError` with `error` because with `onResponseError` it was not processed correctly (it was not redirecting to the `error.vue` page).